# json data return nil in swift

Tags: ios, swift

when I integrated the restful api it returns error

> Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
>   UserInfo=0x17046c680 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with
>   array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})

Can you please tell me why this happens? I coded in swift. Please check following line of code:

```
var jsonResponse  = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(ihelper.responseData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as AnyObject? as? NSArray
```

Comment: Can you give here your response data? Can you check it is in JSON format?

Comment: `... as AnyObject? as? NSArray` What's that?

Answer (score 1):

If you don not know whether it starts with dictionary or array you better to go through the Online JSON Viewer where you can paste your json response and identify the data.

If json starts with  Dictionary(Dictioanry starts with {....} in json response),you need to use

```
  if let jsonResponse: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(ihelper.responseData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as? NSDictionary
  {
     println("Response are\(jsonResponse)")
  }
```

If json starts with  Array(Array starts with [....] in json response),you need to use

```
  if let jsonResponse: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(ihelper.responseData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as? NSArray

  {
     println("Response are\(jsonResponse)")
  }
```